# Struct check type | Swift

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, uitableview

Have the structure where contains 2 types - image and text. Have an array, where it will be added. How to make type check in cellForRowAtIndexPath?

```
struct typeArray {
    var text: String?
    var image: UIImage?

    init(text: String){
        self.text = text
    }

    init(image: UIImage){
        self.image = image
    }
}

var content = [AnyObject]()
```

Image add button:

```
    let obj = typeArray(image: image)
    content.append(obj.image!)
    self.articleTableView.reloadData()
```

Text add button:

```
    let obj = typeArray(text: self.articleTextView.text as String!)
    self.content.append(obj.text!)
    self.articleTableView.reloadData()

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell{

    if content[indexPath.row] ==  {

        let cell = self.articleTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Text Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TextTableViewCell

        cell.textArticle.text = content[indexPath.row] as? String

        return cell

    }

    else if content[indexPath.row] ==  {

        let cell = self.articleTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Image Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell

        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.imageArticle.image = content[indexPath.row] as? UIImage

        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is not the place to be building arrays; there is no guarantee as to which order this function will be called in; you need to use the supplied `indexPath` to determine which row you are operating on

Comment: @Paulw11 what can you advice at this situation?

Comment: I would suggest that you have a single array of structs where each struct can hold text or an image and then use this in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @Paulw11im new in iOS and Swift too, how can i create array with couple types? var array = [AnyObject]()?

Comment: Create a struct with two optional properties; an image and a string. Set the image/string as appropriate and put these in the array. Then you can tell by checking the properties for nil whether it contains an image or a string

Comment: @Paulw11thank you! i will try

Comment: @Paulw11how to make the checking? i've updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should declare your `content` array to hold instances of your `typeArray` struct;

```
var content = [typeArray]()
```

Then add instances of the struct to the array:

```
let obj = typeArray(image: image)
content.append(obj)
self.articleTableView.reloadData()
```

Then you can use this in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` -

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let rowStruct = content[indexPath.row] {
    if let text = rowStruct.text { 
       let cell = self.articleTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Text Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! TextTableViewCell
       cell.textArticle.text = text
       return cell 
    } else if let image = rowStruct.image {
        let cell = self.articleTableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Image Cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! ImageTableViewCell   
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
        cell.imageArticle.image = image
        return cell
    }
    return UITableViewCell()
}
```

Comment: crashes on  let rowStruct = content[indexPath.row], "Cannot call value of non-function type vc.typeArray"

Comment: i did if let text = content[indexPath.row].text and it works fine

Comment: You need to add instances of the struct, not the image to the array.  See my edit